# BlackBerry:List Field-How to Highlight only the text instead of the whole field

Tags: blackberry, java-me, listfield

I have a list field displaying text, and I want only the text to display as focused when the field is selected.  Instead of the whole field being highlighted in blue, I want only the text to be highlighted.

I have found methods to change the highlight color, but not how to limit the area being highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but you should be able to do just override `drawFocus()` to do nothing (that will get rid of the highlighting), and then in your `drawListRow()` check if the row is the selected row, and if that's the case draw the text a different color.

Comment: That was my first thought too, But my Boss wants me to leave the text colour alone, and just contain the highlight area to the text. Thanks though.

Comment: Even after i overrode the drawfocus, i was not able to get rid of the highlight. i mean, i managed to get only the text highlighted, but that was on TOP of the original full field highlight. How do i get rid of the original highlight?

Comment: You may also have to override `drawHighlightRegion()`

Comment: thanks a lot. sorry for the delay. with all the other work, i completely forgot to mention that it worked-